# Undefined Offset error PHP

Tags: php

Having an interesting problem with a piece of legacy web application I am working on, I keep getting the following error:
`Notice: Undefined offset:` 0,1,2,3, etc etc

I have a jQuery tablesorter that sorts the data based on user input. This error *only* occurs for results that are on page 2+.

So if I go to update the results on page 1, everything is fine, I do not get the above Offset Error. However,any page other than 2 throws me that above offset error.

The following is the php code that is generating the error:

```
if(count($_POST)>0) {
 if ($_POST['action'] == "update"){
  // find out how many records there are to update
  $size = count($_POST['review_id']);

  // start a loop in order to update each record
  $i = 0;
  while ($i < $size) {
  // define each variable
  $approved = $_POST['approved'][$i];
  $banned = $_POST['banned'][$i];
  $review_id = $_POST['review_id'][$i];
  //var_dump($approved);
  //var_dump($banned);
  //var_dump($review_id);
  if (isset($_POST['delete'][$i])){
   $delete = 1;
  } else {
   $delete = 0; 
  }
```

The $approved, $banned and $review_id are the ones that cause the errors. The `var_dump` seems to output the string when the results are on page. however, on any pages greater than one all the `var_dump` outputs is NULL NULL NULL respectively.

I have checked with Firebug and all the select forms are named appropriately `<select name="approved[4]" id="select2">` even the ones on page 2 `<select name="approved[79]" id="select2">`

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** If I change the amount of rows delivered to page one it works fine. By that I mean: If I let PHP display 50 rows on the first page as opposed to the 25 currently, it updates correctly. So any amount of results on page 1 updates fine, any results that may flow over to page 2 and beyond - **do not!**.

Comment: It sounds silly, but have you tried simply checking to see if the value is in `$_POST['approved[4]']`?

Comment: Check my recent edit. It works fine - as long as the data is on page 1.

Comment: Did you tried to var_dump: $_POST['approved'],$_POST['banned'] and $_POST['review_id'] ?

Comment: Yes, I just commented it out in the code for now. But I was for each step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you don't have any data at the key.

1. Do a var dump of the POST and see if there is somewhere the variable nam is overwritten.
2. Please check that the select statement is enclosed by `<form> </form>` after the page is changed. You can do the web developer toolbar > view form informaton.

Comment: Have done a var_dump of post. And, the second page is enclosed between form tags too. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: If var_dump($_POST) is empty, this PHP file won't help. The problem could lie in the file where the form exist.

Comment: $_POST is not empty. it returns the exact same value for both the pages.

Comment: sorry, let me understand this. You have name="selected[1]" .. "selected[20]"  ON page1  and selected[21] .. selected[40] on page2. and you are getting $POST['selected'][1..20]  on both pages in the DUMP  instead of $POST['selected'][1..20] on page1 and $POST['selected'][21..40] on page2.. correct ?